# Re: Dual Stack IPv6 routing destination unreachable

Tags: google-compute-engine

Setup a vm with dual stack IP - IPv4 and IPv6 out of which IPv4 is working properly but IPv6 routing destination unreachable. Adding screenshot of routing table for IPv6 along with ping result. We have double checked and tested the apache configuration and it is correct.

IPv4 - https://34.93.43.208
IPv6 - 2600:1900:40a0:4643:0:0:0:0

I'm tiered of this thing, really this sucks. I'd tried nginx as a reverse proxy, php fpm settings and more but no luck.
Only thing I achieved is ping. Now I can ping on IPv6 from other networks.

I did change my dns hosting to GoDaddy now, as there was a problem in NS IPv6.

[image]

**Update on 16th Aug 2023,**

I'd tried curl -g -6 'http://[2600:1900:40a0:4643::]' from vm itself and it works fine.

But when I tried from my laptop or other networks it gives error
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2600:1900:40a0:4643:: port 80: No route to host

Comment: Did you setup/enable IPv6 in the Google Cloud VPC? Edit your post and show the VPC subnet configuration.

Comment: Yes VPC subnet is configured and also enabled IPV6, as I've mentioned it is a dual stack IP configuration. I've updated with VPC subnet ss.

Comment: Have you tried to ping the VM's IPv6 from another machine on the same network?<br>